# How can I tell if this is a split bus panel with no main breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

Looking for the main shut off or to confirm this is a split bus. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is there a service disconnect at the meter?  If so, it a breaker?

Comment: Daniel, I did not have it open, an inspector did and trying to interpret the report. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post which of the two-pole breakers control what?

Comment: General announcement: "Buss" isn't a word. It's the name of a fuse manufacturer (Bussmann, actually), which understandably causes confusion in cases like this. The correct spelling is "bus", as in a means of distribution to multiple points. As you were.

Comment: Does the sticker inside, right give any information on the type of panel? Is there a sticker on the inside of the dead front or the hinged door (if there is one)? The sticker inside the hinged door on my GE panel states 26 poles maximum. I currently have 24 poles installed. To get to 26 I would have to replace the two 2" wide 2-pole breakers on the left upper with three 1" wide compact 2-pole breakers. This would leave two 1/2" slots (top and bottom) in which I would not be allowed to place 1/2" wide breakers. This arrangement would require 5 flips to cut power.

Answer (score 1):

The arrangement of the breakers looks like my 50-year-old GE split bus panel. With the dead front off I can see the wires that go from the lower right hand one of the four 2-pole breakers at the top to the lower bus. In my panel the lower right 2-pole breaker is a 60-A breaker which feeds the lower bus for all the 1-pole breakers below.

In your panel it looks to me like the **lower left** 2-pole breaker has two heavy wires which "disappear" under the 1-pole breakers and so may connect to the lower bus. If you switch off this breaker, does this cut power to all the 120-V circuits?

What are the four 2-pole breakers powering? In mine they are (CW from lower left) electric dryer 30 A, a/c condensing unit 40 A, electric range 50 A and "main" 60-A feeding the 1-pole breakers below.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the wires for the breakers in the top 12 spaces.  In a Rule-of-Six panel, one will "disappear". Jim Stewart discusses this well and no need for me to repeat it in detail.

This type of panel should be grandfathered.  However, if you need to change to a non-Rule-of-Six panel, here's an interesting thing.  Eaton makes panel retrofit kits which replace all the panel "guts".  They are meant for replacing FPE and Zinsco panels, but **they are CH** just like your panel.

You would need a **main breaker** panel, or a no-lug panel set up to backfeed from the top left breaker position.

That looks like the older style "narrow" CH panels, before they widened out to 14.5" (space between 16" joists) to accommodate thick wire bends.  *You won't find a new CH panel whose guts and lid would bolt into this one. I've looked.*

This was a 20?24? (practically: 18/22) space panel. That's just way too small for the modern age. You might also go with a much larger panel, e.g. 42 space, though it would require lots of work including some drywall. Honestly if I were you, I'd just stay with CH, it's a fine industrial-grade type.

Comment: Looks to me like that open space above the top pair of 2-pole breakers could accept one or two 1-pole breakers. Could one put a 1-pole breaker in each side of that space (that would give 6 flips to cut all power)? If this is the case, then one could install three more 1-pole breakers, right?

Comment: @JimStewart that would imply a 22-space panel, which would be weird.  Wait. *Come to think of it, a  20-space panel is also weird for CH*. (Since CH also comes in 3-phase, they like multiples of 3). We're seeing some parallax, another 2 bars are hidden.  **You're right, this is a 24-space panel** with a full six 2-pole blocks in the rule-of-six area, the top 2 unused.  If the knockouts allow, you could put two 1-space 1-pole breakers up there (or for that matter, 2-pole 2-space) and still be inside the rule of six.

Answer (score 1):

How can you tell? it looks like a standard cutter hammer main lug panel,  there is probably a main breaker at the service. To know for sure turn off the top double pole breakers and pop them out. If you see a solid bus running down that is what it is a standard main lug panel. If the bus is split and the bottom is fed from one of the upper breakers it could be a rule of 6 but looking at the wiring I don't think it is.

Comment: Left side, second 2-pole from the top. Where are those fat wires going?

Comment: I can't make them out on my phone, if they feed the lower buss it would be a rule of 6.

Comment: You are correct. Split bus panels were made illegal in the mid to late 60's. The picture shows a Cutler Hammer type CH panel. These panels and breakers weren't made when split busses were used. So it is not a split bus. There may be some that argue they still make split bus panels but the NEC added special conditions for these panels such as complete separation and isolation of the six disconnects and the branch breakers. This has made them financially unappealing.